# how can I wok my hitbox when it collides with something on top of it

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

Im making a game which is meant to be complete chaos and one of the things I did was put falling lava. but My problem is with the collision detection.

```
if Falling_Lava.y - Falling_Lava.width < man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] and Falling_Lava.y + Falling_Lava.width > man.hitbox[1]:
        if Falling_Lava.x + Falling_Lava.width > Falling_Lava.x and Falling_Lava.width < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2]:
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            points -= 5
            man.hit()


if Falling_Lava1.y - Falling_Lava1.width < man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] and Falling_Lava1.y + Falling_Lava1.width > man.hitbox[1]:
        if Falling_Lava1.x + Falling_Lava1.width > Falling_Lava1.x and Falling_Lava1.width < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2]:
            pygame.time.delay(10)
            points -= 5
            man.hit()
```

What Happens is when the falling lava gets to the to the top of your y coordinate it starts diminishing your health even if your x coordinte is not equal to the falling lava's x

[image: What I said explained]

and I don't think its anything wrong with my player hitbox because it works perfectly when you get hit by the zombie

```
def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.velo = 8
    self.left = False
    self.right = False
    self.walkcount = 0
    self.Idlecount = 0
    self.guncount = 0
    self.gunisfired = False
    self.isIdle = False
    self.standing = True
    self.punchislaunched = False
    self.punchcount = 0
    self.hitbox = (self.x + 20, self.y, 28, 60)
    self.health = 10
```

Can someone explain this please

In case you need the full code, go to my [GitHub](https://github.com/ZeeScratcher/Errors-from-the-2D-post-apocolyptic-shooter-/blob/main/Download%20me/Lil_Shooter.py)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your collision checks are a bit messed up. In the x-value if check, you put `Falling_Lava.x + Falling_Lava.width > Falling_Lava.x and Falling_Lava.width < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2]`, where you compare `Falling_Lava` to itself. try replacing `Falling_Lava.x` with `man.hitbox[0]`. I'm not exactly sure if that's the right fix, but I hope this helps.

Edit:

Here is the code you wrote. Everything looks fine except for the 2nd line's first comparison.

```
if Falling_Lava.y - Falling_Lava.width < man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] and Falling_Lava.y + Falling_Lava.width > man.hitbox[1]:
    if Falling_Lava.x + Falling_Lava.width > Falling_Lava.x and Falling_Lava.width < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2]:
        pygame.time.delay(10)
        points -= 5
        man.hit()
```

Corrected example, changing `Falling_Lava.x` to `man.hitbox[0]` (remove the arrows in the actual code, just to point out where...):

```
if Falling_Lava.y - Falling_Lava.width < man.hitbox[1] + man.hitbox[3] and Falling_Lava.y + Falling_Lava.width > man.hitbox[1]:
    # Try replacing this line!
    if Falling_Lava.x + Falling_Lava.width > --> man.hitbox[0] <-- and Falling_Lava.width < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2]:
        pygame.time.delay(10)
        points -= 5
        man.hit()
```

Comment: when you said that I should replace Falling_Lava.x with man.hitbox[0] I need to where i should

Comment: I added some more explanation about where it goes. Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your help when you explianed it in more detail it made sense. :)

Comment: wait I just noticed. if you go to the left of the falling lava you still lose health

Comment: I think in the second half of the x if-check, you put `Falling_Lava.width < man.hitbox[0] + man.hitbox[2]`. Maybe try replacing `Falling_Lava.width` with `Falling_Lava.x`

Comment: Thanks for the advice but unfortunately it did not work

Comment: if you need the full code to find the answer just visit my github https://github.com/ZeeScratcher/Errors-from-the-2D-post-apocolyptic-shooter-/blob/main/Download%20me/Lil_Shooter.py#L67